# How to close the overlay anchor link menu when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**My problem is that , when i open the hamburger menu and click on a navigation link, it does take me to the anchor link section but overlay nav menu doesnot close !**

i did tried to make a close css class and toggle class to the jquery nav but it also doesnot work.

My HTML codes are:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#fullnav').toggleClass('open');
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hamburger-menu').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('change');
  })
});
```

```css
.fullnav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #333333;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, height .35s;
  transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, height .35s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hamburger-menu {
  width: 45px;
  height: 35px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  right: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 500;
}

.line {
  width: inherit;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #7A7A7A;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.line-2 {
  height: 3px;
}

.change .line-1 {
  transform: translate(-4px, -4px) rotateZ(-45deg);
}

.change .line-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .line-3 {
  transform: translate(-4px, -3px) rotateZ(45deg);
}

.fullnav.open {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
}

.fullnav.close {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 0%;
}

.fullnav.open li {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
  animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .35s;
  animation-delay: .35s;
}

.fullnav.open li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: .4s;
  animation-delay: .4s;
}

.fullnav.open li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: .45s;
  animation-delay: .45s;
}

.fullnav.open li:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: .50s;
  animation-delay: .50s;
}

.fullnav nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: Montserrat-Light;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 7rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.fullnav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.fullnav ul li {
  display: block;
  height: 25%;
  height: calc(100% / 4);
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fullnav ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fullnav ul li a:hover:after,
.fullnav ul li a:focus:after,
.fullnav ul li a:active:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.fullnav ul li a:hover::before,
.fullnav ul li a:focus::before,
.fullnav ul li a:active::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.fullnav ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 3px;
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: .35s;
  transition: .35s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="hamburger-menu" id="toggle">
    <div class="line line-1"></div>
    <div class="line line-2"></div>
    <div class="line line-3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="fullnav" id="fullnav">
    <nav class="fullnavMenu" id="fullnavMenu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#a">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#b">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#c">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#d">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code on closeing the overlay nav menus is not working. plz help me fix it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('fullnav').hide();

 });
```

[image]

Comment: You are missing the `#` in the selector here: `$('fullnav').hide();`

Comment: @Turnip i fixed the #fullnav  But now it does not even shows the overlay when i click on hamburger. So forget this part of code but how can i close the overlay upon clicking any nav menu links? i updated a screenshot too.

Comment: You have nothing in your code that would close the menu when the links are clicked. You need something like: `$('#fullnavMenu a').on('click', function() { /* Remove classes from menu etc */ });`

Comment: @Turnip i wrote this code but it does the job done but only for 1 time next time it does not even show the overlay which contains the nav menues:                          $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#fullnavMenu a').on('click', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $('#fullnav').toggleClass('close');
    });
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind a click event handler to the links. Within this even handler, remove the classes that define the open state of the menu.

```js
$("#toggle").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $("#fullnav").toggleClass("open");
});

$(".hamburger-menu").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("change");
});

$("#fullnavMenu a").on("click", function() {
  $(".hamburger-menu").removeClass("change");
  $("#toggle").removeClass("active");
  $("#fullnav").removeClass("open");
});
```

```css
.fullnav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #333333;
  z-index: 100;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, height .35s;
  transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, height .35s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hamburger-menu {
  width: 45px;
  height: 35px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  right: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 500;
}

.line {
  width: inherit;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #7A7A7A;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transform-origin: right;
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.line-2 {
  height: 3px;
}

.change .line-1 {
  transform: translate(-4px, -4px) rotateZ(-45deg);
}

.change .line-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change .line-3 {
  transform: translate(-4px, -3px) rotateZ(45deg);
}

.fullnav.open {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
}

.fullnav.close {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: visible;
  height: 0%;
}

.fullnav.open li {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
  animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .35s;
  animation-delay: .35s;
}

.fullnav.open li:nth-of-type(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: .4s;
  animation-delay: .4s;
}

.fullnav.open li:nth-of-type(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: .45s;
  animation-delay: .45s;
}

.fullnav.open li:nth-of-type(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: .50s;
  animation-delay: .50s;
}

.fullnav nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: Montserrat-Light;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 7rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.fullnav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.fullnav ul li {
  display: block;
  height: 25%;
  height: calc(100% / 4);
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
}

.fullnav ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fullnav ul li a:hover:after,
.fullnav ul li a:focus:after,
.fullnav ul li a:active:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.fullnav ul li a:hover::before,
.fullnav ul li a:focus::before,
.fullnav ul li a:active::before {
  width: 100%;
}

.fullnav ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 3px;
  background: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: .35s;
  transition: .35s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <div class="hamburger-menu" id="toggle">
    <div class="line line-1"></div>
    <div class="line line-2"></div>
    <div class="line line-3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="fullnav" id="fullnav">
    <nav class="fullnavMenu" id="fullnavMenu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#a">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#b">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#c">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#d">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you turnip for your kind help.